# How do I use 'gtag_report_conversion' when tracking conversions in Google AdWords in React.js?

Tags: reactjs, google-ads-api

I don't understand how to use this.
The instructions say to call `gtag_report_conversion` when the action I want to track happens. I want to track signup to my site, so I know that the action was completed in my reducers actions file after I get a confirmation fo succesful signup.

How do I use this `gtag_report_conversion`? What is it? Is it a function? How do I call it? There's surprisingly almost no info in the instructions.

How does AdWords even know which action it is I was trying to track? What if I am trying to track a bunch of different actions, how does it know which is which if all it asks me is to call `gtag_report_conversion`

Would love some clarification as I currently have no idea what to do with this info. PLus these things can take hours to propegate so I can't just tru and chack the console to see if it worked or not.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to run the script (Helmet) inline:

```
<Helmet>
    <script>
        gtag_report_conversion ();
    </script>
</Helmet>
```